# How to create a Vertical Timeline using Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, timeline

I tried to recreate this using tailwind css and I failed . How to create a vertical line between the circles as shown in the image?

I'm trying to show a list of events in a timeline.
[Code link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Pfj7oXPjeZ)
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Pfj7oXPjeZ

Thanks in advance

[Tailwind vertical time line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ji0.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2lnvm6wbTs)

```
<div class="container bg-gray-200 mx-auto w-full h-full">
  <div class="relative wrap overflow-hidden p-10 h-full">
    <div class="border-2-2 absolute border-dashed border-blue-500 h-full border" style="left: 5.8%"></div>


    <!-- First timeline -->
    <div class="mb-8 flex justify-between items-center w-full">
      <div class="order-2 w-6/12"></div>
      <div class="z-20">
        <div class="my-4 rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center bg-indigo-300 ring-4 ring-indigo-400 ring-opacity-30">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-10 w-10 text-green-600" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="order-1 bg-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl w-5/12 px-6 py-4">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <h3 class="mb-3 font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl">Status</h3>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="red">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.05 4.05a7 7 0 119.9 9.9L10 18.9l-4.95-4.95a7 7 0 010-9.9zM10 11a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
          <h5 class="mb-3 font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl">Loc</h5>
        </div>

        <p class="text-base leading-snug tracking-wide text-gray-900 text-opacity-100">statusinfo helooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Second timeline -->
    <div class="mb-8 flex justify-between items-center w-full">
      <div class="order-2 w-6/12"></div>
      <div class="z-20">
        <div class="my-4 rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center bg-indigo-300 ring-4 ring-indigo-400 ring-opacity-30">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-10 w-10 text-green-600" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="order-1 bg-red-200 rounded-lg shadow-xl w-5/12 px-6 py-4">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <h3 class="mb-3 font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl">Status</h3>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="red">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.05 4.05a7 7 0 119.9 9.9L10 18.9l-4.95-4.95a7 7 0 010-9.9zM10 11a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
          <h5 class="mb-3 font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl">Loc</h5>
        </div>

        <p class="text-base leading-snug tracking-wide text-gray-900 text-opacity-100">statusinfo helooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- you can add more time line from here :) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Happy coding :)